# Cat has giardia which is apparently not going away. Help appreciated!

Tags: cats, parasites

Our male cat, born April 3, 2021, has had diarrhea since July 1 and has tested positive for Giardia 13 times since then, as well as a diarrhea profile, which was extensive and expensive.
We have done seven treatments with metronidazole and two treatments with fenbendazole, each for 3-4 weeks, as well as a hygiene cleaning program. We use Halamid and GiardienEx and every time he does a number two we empty the litter box  and disinfect the entire room and clean the litter box and food bowls with boiling water.

The last one ended today with Fenbendazole, Panacur KH 500 (500 mg), which lasted 5 days. We also give him pro-biotics to try to restore his gut flora. We also give him only mono-protein food, meaning no grains or sugar - supposedly it's pure meat - usually easily digestible chicken or turkey. During the treatment we shower him with a cat shampoo and wipe him with a foam that also kills giardia.

The cat has also been housed in smaller and smaller rooms to facilitate, even allow, complete disinfection of the home, plus we have been flooding the rooms with ozone and UV-C light for several months.

At the moment the diarrhea is increasing again and is at 4-5 times a day (record was 10 times, in the meantime the average was 6-7 times), extremely liquid and smells stern. This morning there was a double hit with some mucus and blood.

The cat probably comes from a breeder who sold the cat as a mixed breed, half Main-Coon half European Shorthair for 300€. It is a European Shorthair cat.
This was bought by an acquaintance of my girlfriend when she was 2 months old. The acquaintance found out that she has an allergy and so the cat came to us on July 10.
At the handover it was said that the cat had already had diarrhea for 10 days. The cat was then the next working day the first time at a vet.
There it was said that first the fever is to get under control.

The fleas and the fever went away and even though the cat was never in top shape, he is now vaccinated and chipped.
The neutering and a play partner will have to wait until he is fit....

We would be very grateful for tips, or if a treatment would still be possible or if the Giardia are meanwhile resistant against all medicines.

Neither the vets nor the clinic were much help and proved to be incompetent in more ways than one.

FYI we are in Germany.

Comment: Did you read the articles about Giardia and Giardiasis on Wikipedia? Two points I think are interesting: 1. Humans can have this parasit without symptoms and even knowing but are able to infect others and 2. an infection can cause other illnesses like Reizdarmsyndrom or allergies which would stay when the infection is over. I am no cat experied person, so I can not help further, but wish the best!

Comment: Thank you for the kind wishes. Yes, we have read the article on giardia on Wikipedia, as well as many others on the internet. We have already tested ourselves for giardia, which was negative. I think there are some strains that can infect both humans and cats, and some only cats, so I suspect it's the latter since we've been living with it for quite a while.